# Killed in battle / Killed in a battle?

Tags: articles

I would like to know why the phrase "Killed in battle" is grammatically correct. Why does one not need to put the article "a" there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A lot of nouns can be used two ways:

- As a *concrete* noun, illustrating a specific instance of a concept.  These appear as *count nouns*.  For example:

  - **a** fierce *battle*
  - **an** ancient *culture*
  - **three** *deaths*
  - **a** college *education*
  - perpetrating **a** great *evil*
  - **a** disturbing *experience*
  - **a** close *friendship*
  - **my** first *love*
  - **a** profound *melancholy*
  - **a** rare *opportunity*
  - **an** uneasy *peace*
  - **an** unsafe *speed*
  - **a** good *time*
  - **the** great *war*
- As an *abstract* noun, illustrating the concept in general.  These appear as *mass nouns*.  For example:

  - died in *battle*
  - promoting *culture* and the arts
  - avoiding *death* at all costs
  - believe in compulsory *education*
  - all that is necessary for *evil* to triumph
  - a job that requires *experience*
  - valuing *friendship* above all else
  - *love* is all that matters
  - there is *melancholy* in the wind and sorrow in the grass
  - *opportunity* is a rare thing
  - seeking *peace*
  - *speed* is a scalar quantity
  - *time* waits for no man
  - *war* is a racket

I used the same words in both sets.  (I apologize for the clumsy choice of examples--I picked whatever came to mind first.  Some of them are quotes or collocations.)  In the first set, they were count nouns, so they needed determiners (a category which includes not only articles such as **a**, but also words like **my** and **three**).  In the second set, the same words didn't need determiners.

Let me look at the examples I chose for your word, *battle*, so I can go into more detail:

- **a** fierce *battle*: This describes a single battle.  This particular battle was fierce.  In this phrase, *battle* is a concrete noun because it describes a specific instance of the concept of "battle".  For this reason, it needs a determiner.
- died in *battle*: This describes the concept of battle in general, so it's an abstract noun.  It doesn't describe the particular battle in which they died.  All we know is that they were fighting when they died.  So, this doesn't need a determiner.

As you can see, both are grammatical.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! This is very useful for me :)

Comment: "He died in a battle" When someone speaks this, should it be conceived that the the speaker does not know in which battle did he die? I personally would use an `a` in these constructs regardless of the fact I know about the battle or not.

Comment: @Mistu4u Both are grammatical.  *He died in a battle* refers to a single, unspecified battle.  This sentence doesn't tell us whether or not the speaker knows which battle.  *He died in battle* specifies the state he was in when he died (the state was *in battle*, which is to say, he was fighting).  It's quite odd to talk about someone dying in a particular battle without bothering to specify which one, so *in battle* is more natural.  If you're going to talk about a particular battle, you're more likely to specify which one: "He died in the Battle of the Bulge." or "He died in battle."